# Spring naming policies

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to deploy my Spring project in tomcat, but I am facing this problem:

```
> Información: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext 2014-07-09
> 18:51:24,838 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context
> initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: security.LoginService
> security.LoginController.service; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/config/security.xml]: Initialization of bean
> failed; nested exception is **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/cglib/core/SpringNamingPolicy**   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>   at ....
```

Comment: You're missing a dependency or you're mixing versions of support libs?

Comment: You need to add jar for class org/springframework/cglib/core/SpringNamingPolicy in your classpath.

Comment: It happens when you have in classpath multiple spring-aop libraries with different versions. If you are using spring-security, second spring-aop library is depenedensy for spring-security-config

Comment: @user1516873 very helpful information. Least version of spring-aop is the culprit in my case

Answer (score 1):

Note for future archaeologist: I've noticed similar issue while trying to add 'global-method-security' to web application using old Spring **3.2.6**.

Root cause: missing class org.springframework.cglib.core.SpringNamingPolicy

Solution: update Spring to at least **3.2.8** (spring core to be precise)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```